# Differentiate between Ctrl+Click and Right Click in Qt

Tags: macos, qt, qml

I currently receive mouse events through a `MouseArea` in QML. I can distinguish between left, right and middle mouse press. On Mac, holding Control and Left Clicking is interpreted as a Qt.RightButton press. Is there anyway to distinguish between a standard Right Click and a (Ctrl + Left) Right Click? I need to do this to handle a custom UI interaction (I understand it's an Anti-pattern).

Note: In particular, I need to distinguish between a Ctrl + Left Click and a Ctrl + Right Click. As a result, simply detecting that Control is pressed while a right click event is received isn't good enough.

```
function button( mouse )
    {
        if( mouse.button == Qt.LeftButton )
        {
            console.log("left button is pressed");
            return 0;
        } else if( mouse.button == Qt.MidButton )
        {
            console.log("mid button");
            return 1;
        } else if ( mouse.button == Qt.RightButton )
        {
            console.log("right button pressed");
        }
 }
```

Comment: I'm not that into QML, but I suppose you should just look for modifiers: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mouseevent.html#modifiers-prop

Answer (score 4):

On a Mac, holding Control and Left Clicking to do a Right Click is a system setting, and is a choice the user has - it has nothing to do with Qt, and attempting to detect it breaks your application, since the user depends on Ctrl+Left to act as Right, everywhere, and there's 0 reason for you to change that - just as there's zero reason to prevent the user from e.g. swapping left and right buttons globally (independent and unknown to your application), etc.

The mode of thinking you need is that Ctrl+Left is not available on a default Mac system, and indeed: why would it? If a cross-platform application uses Ctrl+Left/Right on Windows, I'd fully expect it to use Cmd+Left/Right on Mac, and would be quite confused if it did something else. Ctrl on Windows/Unix becomes Cmd on Mac - that's what everyone expects, that's how essentially everything works on Mac. That's what you want - and then there's no problem.

Comment: While I entirely agree with everything you're saying, the mode of thinking I'm trying to get at is as follows:

Imagine you're working on a legacy application that happens to have used Ctrl+Left Click for some custom UI interaction for many years (such applications do exist) on the mac. You now wish to maintain this behaviour despite committing the "crime" of implementing this anti-pattern for the sake of consistency for the user.

Comment: Are you sure that those applications used Ctrl+Click? Remember that the whole reason for this brouhaha is that Mac used to have a single-button mouse, with a primary button, and Ctrl+primary gave the secondary. Then, when more buttons were added, the primary button became the left button, and the secondary became the right button. I guess the application wasn't on Macs in early 2000s, because there'd have been no way to use it if it also had a use for the secondary on same target - unless what you interpret as Ctrl+left was really secondary button, and was merely documented as "Ctrl+left".

Answer (score 0):

Resolved (in a way...): this is a bug in Qt 5.12 which was fixed upstream already.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).